# How to assign a list to an array, starting from an arbitrary index

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array `arr` that starts with zero (`arr[0]`), goes to 32 (`arr[32]`), then there should be a break until 127 (`arr[127]`) where there is a list until 160 (`arr[160]`). How do I assign the second list into the array without writing out each individual assignment?

What I want to avoid:

```
arr=(
  'a0'
  ...
  'a32'
)
arr[127]='a127'
...
arr[160]='a160'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the second part of the array like so:

```
arr+=(
  [127]='a127'
  'a128'
  ...
  'a160'
)
```

- `[127]=` assigns the 127th element of the array. The next string gets assigned to 128, etc.
- `+=(` adds to array, instead of overwriting. If you wanted to *start* an array at a certain index, you could switch `+=(` for `=(`.

Or you could put it all together:

```
arr=(
  'a0'
  ...
  'a32'
  [127]='a127'
  ...
  'a160'
)
```